# Adding Android styles to Appcelerator View

Tags: android, styles, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'd like to add styles defined in `/app/platform/android/res/values` to an appcelerator Button.

```
<style name="textAppearanceButton" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

When I use this code, it will apply to **all** buttons - which i don't want.
Is it possible to add it on selected buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment this is not possible. I did create a feature request for this some time ago that you can watch to show your interest:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19904